# Navigation menu question SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a team site and to that site I added a wiki and a blog subsite. When I am at the team site the menu is shown in tabs: the current site and its subsites, however, when I go to a subsite (blog or wiki) the navigation shows the subsites order in the hierarchy (example: Portal Site > Team Site > Wiki Site)

If I go to the wiki sites site settings the menu looks like the parent sites navigation (example: Team Site Wiki Site Blog Site).

I want the navigation to look the same on all three sites so whichever I am on I want it to look like:
Team Site Wiki Site Blog Site

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both the Blog and Wiki subsites goto:

Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Top link bar

And then click "Use Links from Parent"

Comment: There is no top link bar in sharepoint 2010

Comment: I create a blog site, and a blank site with wiki list, and both have the top nav bar link. What site template are you using for both? What is the parent site template?

Comment: Parent site is a team site and to that one I add two subsites, blog and wiki (enterprise). The blogs navigation bar have the same layout as the teamsite but the wiki has breadcrumbs showing the hierarchy (which I don't want it to). When I say no top link bar I mean the menu option under look and feel.

Comment: also, when I got to site settings on the wiki the top nav bar looks like I want it to look

Comment: I dont normally put an enterprise wiki under a team site, i normal have enterprise wikis as site collections. What you should do, is create a blank site under your team site called "Wiki" and then add a Wiki list to that blank site. Or just add the Wiki list directly to your team site.

Comment: sounds reasonable. However, I solved the problem by copying the html for the navigation I want from the masterpage in sharepoint designer and pasted into the other masterpage (the one used for wikis) and it worked. However, I mark your reply as a solution because what you described in your last comment is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sharepoint's built-in navigation features to set up the menu in site settings>navigation. Then follow the following solution to style it however you want.

http://sharepoint2010customnavigation.blogspot.com/